# What could be faster for scraping multiple javascript websites using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

Actually i am doing a scraping job to scrape board cards from trello.com (if anyone is familiar with trello, he may already know those who don't it is a dynamic website which contains cards containing information about todo tasks). I have successfully wrote a script in selenium python webdriver which scrapes trello firtst, gets a google maps link from it, goes to the map location, scrapes images of that location, comes back to trello and attaches the link of those images one by one to the card as an attachment.
 
One card takes 1.5 to 2 minutes to complete this process, but i have 6000 cards so i would be definitely screwed if i keep myself to this.
I am looking for someone to kindly tell me a better way to do this. If i use scrapy with splash, would that be faster than this ?
 or i have no other options? 
Thanks in advance...!

Comment: `Selenium` is mostly used for unit testing, and is rarely needed for scraping.  `Scrapy` is a package designed specifically for web scraping, so it will be much more efficient.

Comment: Anyways, this question is off-topic

Comment: Why do you need Selenium? What's wrong with Trello API https://help.trello.com/article/756-trello-api-documentation ?